# I have a datatable works standalone but not in IFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, iframe, datatables

I have a tale that works fine in a standalone html file.  I want to have a scrolling list of links to the left that will load the table with data relative to the selected link (I want it to work something like the W3Schools site).   To do this I created a page with two Iframes:  One for the list the other with my datatable.  The problem is that the datatable stopped working when I loaded it to the Iframe.  What am I missing?

Below is my code:

Main page (index):

```
<html>
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href = "css/Custom.css" />
   <title>Failed Fax Monitor></title>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe id="weeks" src="WeekList.html"></iframe>
    <iframe id="requests" src = "Requests.html" name="Requests" ></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

List frame (weeks)

```
<html>
<head>


     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-859-1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jQuery/datatables.min.css"></link>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href = "css/Custom.css" />
     <script src="jQuery/datatables.min.js"></script>

     <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <!--- hard-coded for now will eventually be populated dynamically -->
    <ul>
        <a href="php/Data.php?Date=20170123">01/23/2017</a>
        <a href="php/Data.php?Date=20170116">01/16/2017</a>
        <a href="php/Data.php?Date=20170109">01/09/2017</a>
        <a href="php/Data.php?Date=20160102">01/02/2017</a>
        <a href="php/Data.php?Date=20161226">12/26/2016</a>
        <a href="php/Data.php?Date=20161219">12/19/2016</a>
        <a href="php/Data.php?Date=20161212">12/12/2016</a>
        <a href="php/Data.php?Date=20161205">12/05/2016</a>
        <a href="php/Data.php?Date=20161128">11/28/2016</a>
        <a href="php/Data.php?Date=20161121">11/21/2016</a>
        <a href="php/Data.php?Date=20161114">11/14/2016</a>
        <a href="php/Data.php?Date=20161107">11/07/2016</a>

    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Frame with datatable (requests)

```
<html>
    <head>
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href = "css/Custom.css" />
         <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"> 
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11">
            <scriptsrc="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jQuery/datatables.min.css"></link>

        <script src="jQuery/datatables.min.js"></script>

         <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {

                 $('#faxList').dataTable( {
                     "pageLength" : 50,
                     fixedHeader: true,
                     paging: false,
                     //"dom": '<"top"iflp<"clear">>rt<"bottom"iflp<"clear">>',
                    "ajax": { 
                        "url": "php/data.php",
                        "dataType": "json",
                        "cache": false,
                        "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        "dataSrc": "transactions"
                    },
                    columns: [
                        { data: 'PROCESS_DATE' },
                        { data: 'PROCESS_STATUS' },
                        { data: 'PDF_FILE_NAME' },
                        { data: 'REF_ID' },
                        { data: 'ADDITIONAL_INFO' }

                    ]
                });

            });
        </script>



    </head>

    <body>


        <h2>NCompass Failed Fax Monitor</h2>
        <br>
        <table width="100%" class="display" cellspacing="0" id="faxList">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Process Date</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>PDF File</th>
                    <th>Reference ID</th>
                    <th>Error Description</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

        </table>
        </body>
     </html>
```

[image]

Comment: What you want to say with "datatable stopped working". Do you see any results in the F12 tools?

Answer (score 2):

It works for me.  Do you think it might be the typo:

```
<scriptsrc="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

...in the requests frame should be...

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but no.  The typo was from my transfer to stack overflow.  It does not exist in my code.

Comment: What does developer tools tell you?

Comment: Or alternatively put it on a public server so we can see it in action.

Comment: Thanks, Dan, but for yuks I moved my javascript to the index page (from requests) and that solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I had the javascript on the wrong page.  Moving it to the main page (instead of in the iframe) solved the problem.